# What is the correct way in UML to have interfaces with properties?

Tags: uml

In the example below I would like to have an interface that define a data structure schema with some properties, here `foo` is a static property of the class. The last inherited class override the property to extend its value. We can imagine a more concrete case where I have a Temperature sensor with a static property that indicate the maximum measurable temperature. A more sensitive sensor is still a sensor that can be used as a "standard" sensor, but it extend the range of measurement.

What is the correct way to write this in UML 2.5?

[image]

Comment: http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm#Interfaces

Comment: Not sure if I properly understood the `Apply "Lollipop" Notation To Indicate That A Class Realizes an Interface`

Comment: Because some interfaces embody general capabilities, rather than an `is a` relationship.  For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx  The lollipop notation illustrates that capability as it applies to a class.